# how to sort a list of tuples with list[i][1] as key from biggest to smallest

Tags: python, sorting, key

This is my list.

```
[('a', 12), ('c', 4), ('b', 3), ('e', 6), ('d', 5), ('g', 50), ('f', 30),]
```

The result for sorting this list would be.

```
[('g', 50), ('f', 30), ('a', 12), ('e', 6), ('d', 5), ('c', 4), ('b', 3)]
```

I tried using:

```
x = sorted(alpha_items, key=lambda x: x[1],)
```

But I need to reverse it.

Can i add another key maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The obvious way is to explicitly use the `reverse` parameter which exists precisely for that purpose:

```
sorted(alpha_items, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

If you're sorting by numbers, you can also just negate them:

```
sorted(alpha_items, key=lambda x: -x[1])
```

Comment: Or `reversed(alpha_items, key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: @Malik, that doesn't work. [`reversed()` doesn't take any keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=reversed#reversed).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Oh, thanks. I never knew that.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I assume you mean `reversed(sorted...`? I had considered that but it gives you an iterator and more importantly I think it's just *wrong* to sort and then reverse instead of sorting in the desired order right away, especially since the reverse parameter exists for that.

Comment: @StefanPochmann No, I meant strictly reversed with a key, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`operator.itemgetter(n)` constructs a callable that assumes iterable object (list, tuple, set) as input an fetches n-th element out of it.

```
In [26]: mylist=[('a', 12), ('c', 4), ('b', 3), ('e', 6), ('d', 5), ('g', 50), ('f', 30),]

In [27]: from operator import itemgetter

In [30]: s_l=sorted(mylist,key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)

In [31]: s_l
Out[31]: [('g', 50), ('f', 30), ('a', 12), ('e', 6), ('d', 5), ('c', 4), ('b', 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not a simple sorting algorithm like bubble?

Basically we check if:

```
a[i][1]<a[i+1][1].
```

If it is the case than we simply swap them.

Repeat.

Check sorting-algorithms.com and take look at the Bubble algorithm animation.

```
>>> a = [('a', 12), ('c', 4), ('b', 3), ('e', 6), ('d', 5), ('g', 50),('f', 30),]  
>>> for elem in range(len(a)-1, 0, -1): 
...   for i in range(elem):
...     if a[i][1]<a[i+1][1]:
...        a[i], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[i]
... 
>>> a
[('g', 50), ('f', 30), ('a', 12), ('e', 6), ('d', 5), ('c', 4), ('b', 3)]
```

Comment: You should explain how and why this code works. Otherwise, it doesn't benefit the original poster.

Answer (score -1):

```
alpha_items.sort(key=lambda s:s[1], reverse = True)
```

Comment: Only the second one works. The first one sorts by _ascending_ value of the _last_ item, which just happens to be the second item.